# Is there a way to snap all Bezier control points and handles to one point on the Z axis?

Tags: bezier-curves

I created a curve that was meant to lay flat but some of the handles / control points seem to be slightly off height from the others leading to overly complicated fills. Is there a way to select all control points and handles and normalize them to a specific height on the Z axis?

I'm having a hard time even finding a spot where I can input that coordinate.

Thank you!

Comment: S + Z + 0, and then use the transform field in the N-panel to set the Z position

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to just make it flat just Select every point <kbd>A</kbd>
Size on Z and set it to 0:

<kbd>A</kbd><kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>

I'd do it by moving it to origin and just doing this and moving it back to the coordinate you're trying to place the curve on.

[image]